# Is it possible to build a tree from a list?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have this data structure:

```
public class Node
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public List<Link> Links {get; set;} 
}

public class Link
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

The data might consist of:

```
Node    Links
--------------------
A       1
B       2, 3
C       4, 5
D       6
```

A is the start node and D is the end node. The nodes in-between are in a fixed order. The result should be a list of 'paths' from A to D which will be:

```
A1->B2->C4->D6
A1->B2->C5->D6
A1->B3->C4->D6
A1->B3->C5->D6
```

Which algorithm can be used to get to the above result?

Comment: "Yes, it's possible". In this case it's simply traversing the tree, as with a simplified [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), and emitting the path. There is no 'special algorithm'.

Comment: @user2864740 To build the tree, should extra nodes be created (eg. A1, B2, etc) instead of just A,B,C,D and link these extra nodes accordingly?

Comment: They are all separate 'nodes'. Node A1 links to [node] B2 and B3; B2 to C4 and C5, etc. It is the case that A* -> B* -> C* -> D*

Comment: You're not trying to build a tree. You're trying to take the cartesian product of your four lists.

Comment: something is wrong, what is the information "B 2,3" means? what exactly marks the connection between A and B nodes??

Comment: @user2864740 Simple DFS didn't output the correct results in this case.

Comment: Then it was implemented incorrectly. If walking A*->B*->C*->D* (A start, D end) as the only paths then it would have emitted the desired results. eg. B2 does *not* link to B3. I said simplified DFS but really it's just recursive loops because of the given conditions stated above. On each base case you'll have built up the path to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this recursive implementation:

```
using System;

public class Node {
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public int[] Links {get; set;} 
}

public class Program
{
    private static Node[] nodes = new[] {
        new Node { Name = "A", Links = new[] { 1 } },
        new Node { Name = "B", Links = new[] { 2, 3 } },
        new Node { Name = "C", Links = new[] { 4, 5 } },
        new Node { Name = "D", Links = new[] { 6 } }
    };

    private static void PrintPath(int depth, string path)
    {
        if (depth == nodes.Length) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach(var link in nodes[depth].Links)
            {
                PrintPath(
                    depth+1, 
                    string.Format("{0}{1}{2} ", path, nodes[depth].Name, link));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintPath(0, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I've replaced the `Link` class with `int` and used arrays instead of lists, but you should get the idea.

Comment: This looks like it might work in my case. How can I change it so that the recursive function returns a list of paths?

Comment: Have a look at the implementation on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5TA52n).

Comment: I'm trying to modify the code to return a list of `paths`, where each path is a list of nodes. I have this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uVHB92 but it's return the wrong paths. What's wrong?

Comment: The problem with your implementation is the line `path.Add(n);`. You can't use the passed-in `path`, instead you have to create a new instance (like I did with the `string.Format(...)` in my example). A working example with a `List<Path>` can be found here: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/qkJO0z](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qkJO0z)